# bootstrap-combobox keyup/keypress event not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, combobox

I am using [bootstrap-combobox](https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox)

```
    <select id="resource" class="combobox input-medium">
        <option></option>
        <option>ExpressSale</option>
        <option>TitleAndDescription</option>
        <option>Catalog</option>
    </select>
```

I want to access the value in jQuery, so i have a keyup event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#resource').keypress(function() {
        alert("he");

    });
});
```

I do not get the alert message. I also tried using .each() and .keyup().

Comment: Do you mean `change`? http://jsfiddle.net/XB56L/

Comment: that works! was wondering if I can make it work for keypress too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document.body).on('change', '#resource', function(){
        alert("he");
 });
```

Comment: .change does the same thing :)

Comment: not really, .on will delegate into any element created dinamically, .change will only work with the elements that were loaded in the dom (i.e not ajax)